# How Can We [Show] And [Hidden] the Tab Onclicking of Menu apps Button in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing an Ionic 2 application and have multiple tabs in my application. I need to `Show and Hide` the top tab when clicking the bottom tabs menu icon.

- As of now when clicking the bottom tabs menu icon the top tab is getting displaying  but if again clicking the button the top tab is not hidden.
- [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7UdOip2DeMX907RZeFOg?p=preview) for reference.

What I am looking for is, on clicking the bottom tab menu apps icon, the above tab need to be `[show] and [hidden]`. on clicking the menu in first time the tab should be display and clicking of second time tab need to be hidden...it's like toggle menu...

In angularjs I can do this field using `ng-hide and ng-show` but I don't know how to do this field in ionic 2.

**On clicking** `tab menu apps Icon`:

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only (click)="x()" >
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**My multiple tab Elements:**

```
    <ion-tabs tabs-only (click)="x()" >
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs tabs-only2 tabbar (click)="x()" [hidden]="hideTopTab" >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**Below function are used to [hidden] the element:-**

```
hideTopTab:boolean=true;
   x(){

this.hideTopTab = false;
}
```

Please update the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7UdOip2DeMX907RZeFOg?p=preview) If you have a solution.

Comment: Hi all any answer for the above question?

Comment: by **the above tab need to be both show and hidden** what do you mean?

Comment: @aravind thanks for your comment, please look into my plunker for reference, now i can able to show the tab when i clicking of menu button, but if i clicked the button again it's not hidden....so please update the solution, thanks...

Comment: Hi aravind please check this link:- http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav for example...i am looking for that `menu fuctionality`...on clicking menu button the list of menus are displaying , again clicking of menu button  list of menus are gets hidden this is what i am expecting in ionic 2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your expectation which is under the  component as per this [**documentation**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/navbar/Navbar/).

I have added the below code to your plunker

```
<ion-toolbar no-border-top>
    <button  ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Menu Bar</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-menu [content]="content" id="menu2">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="danger">
          <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>Menu 1</button>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>Menu 2</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Update 1: As per your requirement, you should have the below code

```
x(){
        this.hideTopTab = !this.hideTopTab;
   }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/23lbiiVElCm0EQhCIsQI?p=preview)**

Comment: hi aravind thanks for your valuable help....but we are not looking for this solution......i tell you, first we are clicking on  the menu button to displaying the tab right...then again if click the same bottom of menu button the same displayed tab need to be hidden that's it....your answer also useful to me....if you know the solution please help me...